# fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master~'

Tags: git

When I try any of these commands:

```
git branch
git branch -a
git pull
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Cblue[%cn]\\%Creset %s" --decorate --graph
git log --online --decorate --graph
```

I get the error

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master~'
```

But the following commands work:

```
git log --oneline --graph # removed --decorate
git log
```

Running

```
find ./ -iname "*conflict*"
```

doesn't return any results.

The output of `find ./ -name "*master*" | grep "\./\.git"` is

```
./.git/logs/refs/heads/master
./.git/logs/refs/heads/master~
./.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
./.git/refs/heads/master
./.git/refs/heads/master~
./.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Don't know if that helps, but I see `master~` in there.

Any idea what might be wrong? What other info can I provide you with?

Comment: does `git co master` works?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal `co` isn't a valid git command, I think you might have meant `checkout`, is that correct?

Comment: @Cupcake yes sorry for that. I really forget the actual commands which I have aliases for.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal Here's the output of `git checkout master`: http://hastebin.com/domimukidi.vbs

Comment: I had a similar incident. Had you run rsync against that directory by any chance? My hunch is that it was something to do with rsync in my case.

Comment: I can confirm that at least in my case, it was definitely due to having run rsync with the --backup option and the git repository in question was the rsync destination.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like some utility has created "backups" of the normal branch files (`.git/refs/heads/...`) with a trailing `~` character. This are not allowed branch names in Git as they would conflict with the suffix notation `...~N` for obtaining ancestors.

Commands that don't need to query all refs (such as `git log master` without `--decorate`) are working but anything that tries to list all branches is choking on the invalid branch name.

Simply delete the file `./.git/refs/heads/master~` (after backing it up) and you should be good to go.

Comment: This worked for me (Dropbox was to blame), I deleted .git\refs\heads\master(1) and .git\refs\remotes\origin\master(1) and now it works!

Comment: This worked for me too. But in my case it was called 'master (Конфликтующая копия с компьютера ***)' because of russian culture setting in OS.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your .git/HEAD file has invalid content. Check this file and if it has the tilde appended to the content remove it. For instance here on one of my repositories:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Some of the files in .git are pointers to other references like this. Git reads them, dereferences the content and uses that as an object reference to go on with.

It might be that the error is on the server side - so you should check that too.

Comment: Doing `cat .git/HEAD` shows `ref: refs/heads/master` just like yours. Any other output I can show you?

Answer (score 2):

### Delete your editor swap/backup files

The files you have found are not related to git - they are created by an editor when opening the filename without the `~`.

Just delete them, and if you want to prevent this problem in the future just configure your editor to *not* create swap/backup files in the same directory as the file you are editing.