# One remote master - one local, one google drive, one dropbox

Tags: git, google-drive-api, dropbox

I'm trying to set up a scenario with Git where I can have one master repository and multiple "locals". The idea is this:

- Have a main repository that everyone pulls and pushes to, say Dropbox or Google Drive, or the work server (which is only accessible in work, unfortunately)
- Have a local copy on my computer at work, home, Dropbox and/or Drive
- My terminology is probably all wrong as I usually do quite simple things with Git

Essentially, I want to be able to work on the same project at work, home, wherever, keeping everything up-to-date with Drive/Dropbox, and having a a backup copy on the work server.

I tried setting up a master repository on the work server with

```
git --bare init myMaster.git
```

Then cloning it to a directory on my computer. That works completely fine and it's what I usually do. I push and pull and commit and everything is wonderful :)

What I want to do now is also have the same but have another repository on Drive/Dropbox/home that I can push and pull to. The only one that would be accessible to all at once is an online one, so the master would be Drive/Dropbox/alternative.

Then wherever I go, I can work on the most recent copy and everything is up-to-date.

**Problem:** When I clone a new repository from the master and try to push using
    get push myMaster

I get the error

```
fatal: the current branch master has no upstream branch, use

get push --set-upstream myMaster master
```

I use that, then

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'ref/heads/master[conflict]
```

Using 
    git remote -v

I get 
    myMaster ../.../../ (server path)

Looks fine. I looked around here and found this: [fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master~'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112204/fatal-reference-has-invalid-format-refs-heads-master)

with the recommendation to "Simply delete the file ./.git/refs/heads/master~ (after backing it up) and you should be good to go."

However, my directories contain only one "master" file. So I'm a bit confused. Does anyone have any suggestions? Even a keyword to search for or a vague tip would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Just a side note: Putting the source code from your work on Google Drive or Dropbox might not be a good idea.

Comment: That sounds ominous... Why's that?

Comment: From a legal/data protection perspective it might not be permitted to do so. Some companies have clauses preventing you from doing that in their contracts.

Comment: Wow I hadn't even thought of that. I'll delete it for now. First job so kind of an idiot. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In general, Git is perfect for this kind of remote work. You can do local commits/branches, and once you're back in your office network, you can sync with the server repo. Try to minimize the number of remotes you're working with. Maybe there's a VPN you can use to connect to the work server when out of the office?

Comment: Great idea, will look into it. Though I think the VPN would only be installed on authorised computers so working on a different computer would be a no-go. Is the principle of what I wanted to do possible at least? Or does Git just not work that way?